# Let's get critical: Oct 2014 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [French Language Stack Exchange](http://french.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://french.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Comment: I am a new user (although I have used SE a lot in the past) and I found asking a question a little tricky - I had no idea what to tag it with, because the tag names are *all* french.

Comment: @Tim We have tag synonyms in English. The displayed name is in French, but you can also type an English word. If you find missing synonyms, please tell us on meta or in chat. Tag wiki excerpts should be bilingual, but we are missing a lot of translations. Is there something we can do that would help? (Other than removing French tag names, which would be a problem for people who don't speak English well, or having user preferences, which Stack Exchange developers haven't agreed to do.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Sens de la phrase « descendre l'escalier »](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/11656/sens-de-la-phrase-descendre-lescalier)

**Net Score: 9** (Excellent: 9, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- ["Continuer de faire" ou "Continuer à faire"](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/11799/continuer-de-faire-ou-continuer-%c3%a0-faire)

**Net Score: 8** (Excellent: 8, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Une traduction pour « les grands gens »](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/11778/une-traduction-pour-les-grands-gens)

**Net Score: 5** (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Ways of referring to names](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/11680/ways-of-referring-to-names)

**Net Score: 5** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 10, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Difficultés avec le subjonctif](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/11666/difficult%c3%a9s-avec-le-subjonctif)

**Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Étiquettes de l'axe des abscisses et des ordonnées dans un graphique : singulier ou pluriel?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/11695/%c3%89tiquettes-de-laxe-des-abscisses-et-des-ordonn%c3%a9es-dans-un-graphique-singulier)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [What's the function of "si" in this sentence?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/11690/whats-the-function-of-si-in-this-sentence)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 9, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Un mot pour spécifier « tous les deux jours » ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/11805/un-mot-pour-sp%c3%a9cifier-tous-les-deux-jours)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 8, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Quel sont les mots d'argot ou familiers utilisés pour l'euro ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/11863/quel-sont-les-mots-dargot-ou-familiers-utilis%c3%a9s-pour-leuro)

**Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 8, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- [Envoyer un e-mail à deux personnes ayant le même prénom](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/11683/envoyer-un-e-mail-%c3%a0-deux-personnes-ayant-le-m%c3%aame-pr%c3%a9nom)

**Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 8, Needs Improvement: 3)

---